# Multiple activities using with android navigation

Tags: android, mvvm, navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I wanna use jetpack navigation in android kotlin.

But my app has 5 activities. Should i create navigation graph for each activities or should i use just one graph?

which one would you recommend?

Comment: Use 1 Activity and 5 Fragments

Comment: but I have to use min 5 activities and around 20-25 fragments...

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Migrate to Navigation guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-migrate):

> While a single-activity architecture allows you to take full advantage of the Navigation component, you do not need to fully migrate your app [to a single activity] to benefit from Navigation.

It specifically states that you should migrate to Navigation on an activity by activity basis, with each activity having its own navigation graph.